# Python 3, Read textfile and separate each line and fill in corresponding variables

Tags: python, list, file, readfile

Firstly I use this:

```
with open(filename) as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):    
        print(i)
        print(line)
        if i == index:
            break
        else:
            continue
```

This makes me able to output each line until ( i ) reaches the amount of the index variable, but this is not all I want, I want to read a file which looks a bit like this :

```
John|Graham|JOB|AGE
Philip|Jefferson|JOB|AGE
```

I want to be able to parse this data into corresponding variables, but! I want to be able to specify which line to read from, so that I can read line 1, parse the data from there, and then line 2, but not as in a loop!, which is the important part.

I want to be able to set the variable ( index ) to let's say 2

then line 2 will parse the first segment "Philip" into the variable NAME.

and so on.

I hope you understand!, I have been so frustrated that I have not been able to come up with a solution.

Comment: So you want to set `index=2`, and then your code will get the line for Philip and store all of his data into separate variables. Is that correct?

Comment: look up the syntax to split()

Comment: I don't understand why it is important not to read in a loop. Do you want to parse a single line or a whole set of lines?

Comment: I agree with Gribouillis, you need to iterate so how else do you expect to do this?

Comment: BTW, `else: continue` at the end of a loop is redundant, the loop's going to continue anyway.

Comment: Will you access different lines in your input file at different times? Or are you just getting a single line and that's it? Often in situations like this, you can (and should) parse the entire file into an appropriate data structure, such as a list, then you can index directly into the list as many times as you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that should work:

first we need to get all the lines read into a list.

```
>>> with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
>>>     lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

now we can index nicely in:

```
>>> print(lines[0])
    John|Graham|JOB|AGE
```

Okay, now we want to split each line into the data we need.

```
>>> first = lines[0]
>>> info = first.split('|')
    ['John', 'Graham', 'JOB', 'AGE']
```

And then to put everything into a variable:

```
>>> NAME, LASTNAME, JOB, AGE = info
>>> print(NAME)
    John
>>> print(LASTNAME)
    Graham
```

Putting it all together:

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

def get_info(lines, line_num):
    line = lines[line_num]
    return line.split('|')

NAME, LASTNAME, JOB, AGE = get_info(lines, 0)
print(NAME) # Prints "John"
```

If you don't want to read in the whole file at once, you can use the same techniques in your script:

```
with open(filename) as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):    
        print(i)
        print(line)
        if i == index:
            NAME, LASTNAME, JOB, AGE = line.split('|')
            break
```

Comment: Thanks, PM 2Ring! Edited.

Comment: This looks like it! Thank you so much, this will help alot!

Comment: @Simontaga Notice how this answer breaks the overall problem into small manageable steps. This is one of the most crucial skills you need to develop as a computer programmer. I hope that this serves as a good example so that you can cultivate this skill yourself as you continue learning how to program. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to allow you to access each line by index:

```
the_dict = {i:a.strip('\n') for i, a in enumerate(open('filename.txt'))}
```

Output:

```
{0: 'John|Graham|JOB|AGE', 1: 'Philip|Jefferson|JOB|AGE'}
```